# Capitalization with compound nouns starting with a number

Tags: style

Consider the technical term *4-terminal*: if I were to start a paragraph with this term, or using it as column heading in a table, would I have to capitalize the *t* or not?

My understanding is that it should not be capitalized because it is the *4* which counts as first symbol, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Are you using title case or sentence case?

Comment: Sentence case: the journal for which I'm writing uses sentence case also for titles and headings.

Comment: If you're using sentence case, then I would go with your interpretation; the first item takes the capital. However, I would spell out "Four" in prose, and I'd even spell it out in the table heading if you have room.

Comment: Thank you! As for the prose, in a technical article it would be very uncommon to see _four-terminal_, also because it derives from the more general term _n_-terminal, where the _n_ is written as a mathematical symbol.

Comment: A common grammar rule is that you should never begin a sentence with a Hindu-Arabic numeral, but instead should spell out the word, and then capitalize it. However, in technical writing, many people ignore this rule because it can be confusing. I doubt I'd write "Sixteen MB of RAM are required ..." instead of "16MB of RAM are required ..." etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the discussion in the comments: if you're using sentence case, I'd go with 4-terminal (lowercase T) because the 4 is the first character.

(I would still flinch to see a sentence which started with "4-terminal" instead of "Four-terminal," but I'm not in technical writing.)

Comment: An example that comes to my mind is that of a caption: one might need to start a sentence with "4-terminal" for reason of compactness. Also in the case of mathematical symbols rules say that you should avoid beginning a sentence with a mathematical symbol (you can't change the capitalization of a mathematical symbol: _x_ is not the same as _X_), but sometimes you are forced to (in this specific case, examples abound).